# How to STOP or ABORT or BREAK the execution of query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Is there a way to immediately stop execution of a SQL script in MySQL server, like a "break" or "exit" command?

I put the statements I want to run in a file "updates.sql", and using MySQL command to execute:

```
mysql -u <username> <dtabase_name> < updates.sql


ALTER TABLE `app_batch`
ADD COLUMN `fee` DOUBLE NOT NULL AFTER `mode`;
ALTER TABLE `app_course` 
DROP COLUMN `course_fee`, 
DROP COLUMN `duration_type`,
DROP COLUMN `duration`,
```

That's my query inside the file.

It's executing `DROP COLUMN` rows event though

```
ADD COLUMN `fee` DOUBLE NOT NULL AFTER `mode`;
```

fails

Comment: for example in my query i have few line like create table "a" ,drop table "b" ,and altering table "a". while execution it creates table "a" and fails at drop because there is no table "b" to drop and it will alter table "a" finally throws error there is no table "b".

Comment: Whenever there is a fail in a sequence of SQL commands, all the statements after the failing one aren't executed. All the previous ones, instead, are kept.

Comment: i want to skip the 3rd step also when the second fails or don't execute 1st also

Comment: You have to provide an example of your script, and explain what you want in a clearer way, then.

Comment: in mys case its executing remaining statements , is there any way to stop entire execution if one statement fails i mean creating table a has to be undo like.

Comment: When you start mysql from command with mysql --help in the list of variables what is force set to?

Answer (score 6):

1. Connect to mysql server using terminal (Use command prompt, If you are using Windows)

   mysql -u[user_name] -p[password]
2. Run following command to list running queries.

> ```
> mysql> show full processlist;
>
> +----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
> | Id | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State    | Info                  |
> +----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
> |  8 | root | localhost | NULL | Sleep   |   25 |          | NULL                  |
> |  9 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | starting | show full processlist |
> +----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+-----------------------+
> 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
> ```

3. Then kill query by process Id

   mysql> kill 9;

Answer (score 0):

Use **`SHOW PROCESSLIST`** to view all connections, and **KILL** the process ID's you want to kill.

```
mysql>show processlist;

mysql> kill "number from first col";
```

or you can KILL complete connection also for stop all query from a specific connection.

Comment: i want to skip the remaining lines of query to skip when one of the line in query fials

Comment: So you can use `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION SET has_error = 1;`

Comment: read http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-error-handling-in-stored-procedures/ for more details